# returning model back to view causes page to break with encType

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I am inheriting a project which is somewhat built in Umbraco 6 and I am not familiar with Umbraco but learning thus far.

A partial view is using an existing template which effectively has this in its template:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
@{
    Layout = "MvcBanner.cshtml";
}

@section ContentPlaceHolderParent { 

 @Umbraco.RenderMacro("Breadcrumb")



@Umbraco.Field("pageName")
@Umbraco.Field("pageInstructions", insertBefore: "", insertAfter: "", convertLineBreaks: true)

    @Html.Action(@Umbraco.Field("MVCActionName").ToString(), @Umbraco.Field("MVControllerName").ToString()) 

}
```

This template is being used by a page "UploadJobs.cshtml"

Now, on the UploadJobs.cshtml I have a few fields bound to a model and then a file upload:

```
@model Models.JobsModel

@using(Html.BeginUmbracoForm("UploadJobs", "Jobs"))

{

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name);


@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Files, new { type = "file", name = "Files" })


<input type="submit" value="Upload" id="cmdSubmitJobs" />

}
```

My action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public PartialViewResult UploadJobs(UploadJobs model)
{ ... }
```

When submitting, everything seems fine but when returning the model back to the view (i.e validation fails), it seems to break the page completely when rendering (i.e all styles and all formatting is gone) and any javascript//jquery functions I have returns errors when the document is being rendered

thoughts? I want to be able to obviously return the model if it is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Ahmed,

your problem is probably because of you are redirecting to the partialview not the view itself. Double check your flow, the partial page is most likely called from another view (parent one). This parent view contains all required styling stuff within it.

Comment: Hi. I did all this.... but no go. the problem I figured out shortly was that if I change the Html.BeginForm() to: @Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null, new { encType = "multipart/form-data" })... then it works. I do not know why I have to specify "home" when the name of the controller is something COMPLETELY different and I have NO home controller!